# Adding to All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to add records to All Subscribers using API. The API request is successful but record is not getting loaded in All Subscribers.

Below is my request and response -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <createrequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <partnerkey xsi:nil="true"></partnerkey>
            <objectid xsi:nil="true"></objectid>
            <emailaddress>maneesh_83@yahoo.co.in</emailaddress>
            <subscriberkey>ID77711</subscriberkey>
            <emailtypepreference>HTML</emailtypepreference>
            <attributes>
                <name>First Name</name>
                <value>John</value>
            </attributes>
            <attributes>
                <name>Last Name</name>
                <value>Smith</value>
            </attributes>
            <attributes>
                <name>LLYSubscriberkey</name>
                <value>ID77711</value>
            </attributes>
            <lists>
                <partnerkey xsi:nil="true"></partnerkey>
                <id>21514</id>
                <objectid xsi:nil="true"></objectid>
                <status>Active</status>   
            </lists>
            <status>Active</status>
        </objects>
    </createrequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:56283953-ab13-43f0-a13b-6d177fb7449a</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:b0b310e2-f57c-482e-a89c-65d27032af98</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-a8995a77-dc64-4630-9680-3f67705683db">
            <wsu:Created>2016-01-13T18:57:58Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2016-01-13T19:02:58Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
        <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RequestID>40e18e3b-40a9-4c92-b75c-b0f9b3766fd3</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should receive a copy of the data you have created as part of the response 
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/creating-a-subscriber.html

I suspect that something is NOT OK with the request, but I admit that the response is misleading.

Comment: I was able to get it working somehow! Did some tweaking in the tags and it worked.. Thanks Germann!